# Nonlinear curve fitting of a matrix function in python

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, non-linear-regression

I have the following problem. I have a N x N real matrix called Z(x; t), where x and t might be vectors in general. I have N_s observations (x_k, Z_k), k=1,..., N_s and I'd like to find the vector of parameters t that better approximates the data in the least square sense, which means I want t that minimizes

S(t) = \sum_{k=1}^{N_s} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{j=1}^N (Z_{k, i j} - Z(x_k; t))^2

This is in general a non-linear fitting of a matrix function. I'm only finding examples in which one has to fit scalar functions which are not immediately generalizable to a matrix function (nor a vector function). I tried using the scipy.optimize.leastsq function, the package symfit and lmfit, but still I don't manage to find a solution. Eventually, I'm ending up writing my own code...any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can do curve-fitting with multi-dimensional data.  As far as I am aware, none of the low-level algorithms explicitly support multidimensional data, but they do minimize a one-dimensional array in the least-squares sense.  And the fitting methods do not really care about the "independent variable(s)" `x` except in that they help you calculate the array to be minimized - perhaps to calculate a model function to match to `y` data.

That is to say: if you can write a function that would take the parameter values and calculate the matrix to be minimized, just flatten that 2-d (on n-d) array to one dimension.  The fit will not mind.